# How to draw an electrical circuit with node numbers in python?

Tags: python-3.x, drawing, draw, python-3.7, circuit-diagram

I have a program that's need a method for ploting an electrical circuit with node numbers(netlist).
It's example of netlist:
number 1 net list:

1. number 1 net list:

R1 1 2 4

R2 2 0 4

R3 2 0 4

I1 1 0 2

2. number 2 net list:

V1 1 0 10

R1 2 1 2

R2 2 0 2

C3 2 3 200u

R4 2 3 10

I5 3 2 2 90

L4 3 0 1m

in this net lists first and second numbers are node numbers and third number is size of electrical component.

Comment: See also: [is-it-possible-to-draw-circuits-through-code](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/336946/is-it-possible-to-draw-circuits-through-code)

Answer (score 1):

You could try [lcapy](http://lcapy.elec.canterbury.ac.nz/).

- Its [component specification](http://lcapy.elec.canterbury.ac.nz/netlists.html#component-specification) is similar to what you describe.

Other Python schematic libraries worth considering:

- [SKiDL](https://xesscorp.github.io/skidl/docs/_site/index.html) (designed to work with [KiCAD](http://www.kicad-pcb.org/))
- [SchemDraw](https://schemdraw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: I use lcapy.It can draw one loop circuit. schemadraw can't get node list and skidl just create a netlist from thing you enter in your code.